# Powershell get a list of drives

Tags: powershell

I'm using this command to get a list of my drives in my `Windows`:

```
get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] }
```

This gives:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
C                 131.85        333.62 FileSystem    C:\
D                 111.15        200.63 FileSystem    D:\
```

What I actually want to get is the list of values under "Root" column.
Basically a string as follows `C:\ D:\`

How can I do that?

**EDIT**:

I Managed to do this:

```
get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] } | Select Root
```

Which Gives:

```
   Root
   ----
   C:\
   D:\
```

How do I convert it to:

```
 C:\ D:\
```

Comment: @LotPings: Where are you picking only the Root. He is expecting to pick the root only

Comment: Use: `Select -Expand Root` But your query has a flaw, depending on the drives (not)available you might get `Cannot index into a null array` on `get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0]`

Comment: @iRon how would you suggest to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] }).Root
```

It will show line by line like:

```
C:\
D:\
```

Else you can do like this to get it side by side:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] }).Root -join " "
```

It will output like this:

```
C:\ D:\
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent errors like:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:82
+ ...  3 } | % {$_.DriveLetter} | % { get-psdrive $_.DriveLetter[0] } | Sel ...
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

I would include `-and $_.DriveLetter` in the `Where` clause.

And I think that there is no need to use `Get-PSDrive` as the required output is already available in the `Name`.

Thus:

```
get-wmiobject win32_volume | ? {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.DriveLetter} | Select -Expand Name
```